# count() method of the list class applied to queryset. Strange behaviour. Django

Tags: python, django

Cant find out  why I keep getting following  following error:

> TypeError at /boats/reversion/
>   count() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

```py
#views
…
…
…

memory_limiter = BoatImage.objects.filter(boat_id__isnull=True).exclude(
    memory__in=existing_boats_pk).values_list("memory", flat=True)

for i in memory_limiter:
    if memory_limiter.count(i)  >  3:
        memory_limiter.remove(i)
```

what shell says about memory limiter:

```py
>>> for memory in memory_limiter:
...     print(memory, type(memory))
...
93 <class 'int'>
93 <class 'int'>
93 <class 'int'>
93 <class 'int'>
93 <class 'int'>
93 <class 'int'>
93 <class 'int'>
100 <class 'int'>
102 <class 'int'>
102 <class 'int'>
102 <class 'int'>
>>> memory_limiter
<QuerySet [93, 93, 93, 93, 93, 93, 93, 100, 102, 102, 102]>
>>>
```

following method brings same results:

```py
for i in [ x for x in memory_limiter]:
    if memory_limiter.count(i) > 3:
        memory_limiter.remove(i)
```

Question is whats wrong with the count? I copy pasted this list to a separate `*.py` module and there it works fine…
Tried to turn qs to iterator -same results.

in separate module

```py
a = [93, 93, 93, 93, 93, 93, 93, 100, 102, 102, 102]

for i in a:
    if a.count(i) > 3:
        a.remove(i)
print(a)

----- >[93, 93, 93, 100, 102, 102, 102]
```

Comment: what are you expect `remove()` to do?

Comment: Don't remove elements while iterating over it.

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM, you can remove objects if you're iterating using indexes from last to first.

Comment: @ Olvin Roght  . have a look on the try in separate .py module( at the end of the text). This is pretty much desireble output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing is wrong with django here.

```
memory_limiter = BoatImage.objects.filter(boat_id__isnull=True).exclude(
    memory__in=existing_boats_pk).values_list("memory", flat=True) # This returns QuerySet object.

for i in memory_limiter:
    # QuerySet class has instance method .count(), but you can not provide parameters. Also, QuerySet does not support remove() method.
    # if memory_limiter.count(i)  >  3:
    print(memory_limiter.count())
```

Your code works on `list`. But Django's `QuerySet` and python's `list` are different objects, with different methods.

But you can do something like this. This should work(IMHO).

```
memory_limiter = list(BoatImage.objects.filter(boat_id__isnull=True).exclude(
        memory__in=existing_boats_pk).values_list("memory", flat=True)) # You should cast QuerySet object into list, then you can operate over it as a normal python's list.
for i in memory_limiter:
    if memory_limiter.count(i)  >  3:
        memory_limiter.remove(i)
```

Comment: @ Olvin Roght . Thanks for the answer. I wraped it all inside list() and all worked. I just thought that value_list + flat=True return list but it is not true

Comment: You are welcome. It returned list in old versions of Django (1.8 for example) as far as i remember. But now, everything returns QuerySet, but you still can to cast it to list.